# C# Method - Publish Entire Sitecore Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sitecore, sitecore7

I have an odd request.  I am wondering if it is possible to have your C# solution file publish the entire Site from the master database to the web database.  I am in my development environment and the amount of items in Sitecore is changing daily as I am working with multiple people.  This is not something that is going to be used to Production Content Management or Content Delivery.  Purely development.

Is it possible to trigger a full Site publish in C# just like pressing the publish button in the content editor?  And what would the code look like?

/sitecore/shell/Applications/Publish.aspx

I assume this C# method would work with Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to publish in dev? I always have my dev instance set up to point to the master db instead of web so there's no need to publish to preview every change.

Comment: As @mdresser says, there is an example `livemode.config` in the default installation `/app_config/include` folder. You could also enable the `PublishAgent` to run at specific intervals to do a full publish http://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/basics-of-sitecore-scheduled-publishing/

Comment: @mdresser Our development instance right now has some workflow stuff integrated with our communication with SQL Server and our Oracle instances.  As we are designing the Sitecore Sites we have employees working on the Oracle integrations.  We could only point to Master but then we could not develop our workflow steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We also use that on our projects...
We have that placed in a regular .aspx page. I hope that helps:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PublishMode publishMode = PublishMode.Full;

    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
        var webDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
        var masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

        try
        {
            foreach (Language language in masterDb.Languages)
            {
                //loops on the languages and do a full republish on the whole sitecore content tree
                var options = new PublishOptions(masterDb, webDb, publishMode, language, DateTime.Now) { RootItem = masterDb.Items["/sitecore"], RepublishAll = true, Deep = true };

                var myPublisher = new Publisher(options);
                myPublisher.Publish();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Could not publish", ex);
        }
    }
}
```